# Reduce by inspecting tuple element

Tags: scala

I want to find the Tuple with the largest second element:

```
mylist.reduce { (x, y) => {
  if (y._1 > x._1) y
  else x
}}
```

Where `x` and `y` are of type `Tuple3[DenseVector[Int], Double, PipelineModel]`.

1. I get the error that `>` cannot be resolved. What's up with that? Using `foldLeft` and providing a zero element did not help either.
2. Can I write the code nicer? (It doesn't look so nice, I think.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a triplet (a, b, c) `triplet._2` gives you the second element.

`_1` gives first element

`_2` gives second element

`_3` gives third element

> Tuples are not zero based.

```
scala> val triplet = (1, 2, 3)
triplet: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)

scala> triplet._1
res0: Int = 1

scala> triplet._2
res1: Int = 2

scala> triplet._3
res2: Int = 3
```

**Answer 1:**

In your case `triplet._1` gives the first element of the triplet (tuple3) which is `DenseVector[Int]` element on which you cannot use `>`. Thats why `>` is not resolved.

**Answer 2:**

#### maxBy

```
l.maxBy(_._2)
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val l = List((1, 2, 3), (0, 0, 1))
l: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (0,0,1))

scala> l.maxBy(_._2)
res1: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)
```

---

#### Reduce

```
l.reduce { (x, y) =>  if (x._2 > y._2) x else y }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val l = List((1, 2, 3), (0, 0, 1))
l: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (0,0,1))

scala> l.reduce { (x, y) =>  if (x._2 > y._2) x else y }
res3: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a very interesting method, that I did not know about. This answers 2) - do you also know the answer to 1?

Comment: @Make42 In your case triplet._1 gives the first element of the triplet (tuple3) which is DenseVector[Int] element on which you cannot use >. Thats why > is not resolved

Comment: @Make42 I gave answer to 1 as well

Comment: "Tuples are not zero based." that was it - aww man... Thanks! I totally forgot. The compiler info was not so helpful in my case :-).